# Работа с потоками

Tags: c#, wpf, потоки-данных

Есть один метод, который выполняется достаточно долго и я хочу отобразить его выполнение в `ProgressBar`. Если этот метод выполняется в главном потоке то интерфейс зависает пока метод не выполниться. Когда запускаю этот метод в отдельном потоке то все работает но если попытаться из вторичного потока обратиться в главный, для изменения `ProgressBar`'а, то все зависает как и в первом случае. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вам как, скопипастить из гугла? Тривиальщина же.

Comment: Хотя бы так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Канонический метод — использование [`BackgroundWorker`'а](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

```
void Start() // необходимо запускать в UI-потоке
{
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += (s, e) => e.Result = BackgroundTask(bw);
    bw.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => DisplayProgress(e.ProgressPercentage);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => DisplayResult((int)e.Result);
}

int BackgroundTask(BackgroundWorker bw) // будет выполнено в фоновом потоке
{
    int result;
    bw.ReportProgress(0);
    // долго считаем
    bw.ReportProgress(50);
    // ещё считаем
    bw.ReportProgress(100);
    return result;
}

void DisplayProgress(int percent) // будет выполнено в UI-потоке
{
    // например:
    label.Text = string.Format("{0}% ready", percent);
}

void DisplayResult(int result) // будет выполнено в UI-потоке
{
    // например:
    label2.Text = string.Format("Calculation produced {0}", result);
    startCalculationButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Красиво написано, я хотел invoke советовать :-( 
Хотя лишнем он не будет, иногда нужно больше информации передавать, чем только прогресс в инте.

Comment: @pincher1519: угу, `Invoke` всё равно пригодится.

Answer (score 3):

Современный метод, подходящий при использовании как WPF, так и других UI-библиотек, состоит в использовании `async / await`:

```
    private async Task<double> DoWork(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        progress.Report(0);
        
        // рассчёт data; используем ConfigureAwait(false) для того,
        // чтобы не захватывать SynchronizationContext вызывающего потока
        // (например, если вызывающий поток -- UI)
        var data = await SomeOtherWork().ConfigureAwait(false);
        progress.Report(50);

        // получаем text через HTTP
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string text = await client.GetStringAsync("http://example.org/foo");
        progress.Report(100);

        // объединяем data и text
        return Combine(data, text);
    }

    private async void buttonStart_Click()
    {
        // предотвращаем одновременный запуск операции
        buttonStart.Enabled = false;

        var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
            {
                // данная лямбда будет вызвана в SynchronizationContext,
                // захваченным при создании Progress<T>; для UI -- в UI-потоке
                labelProgress.Text = string.Format("{0}% ready", percent);
            });
        // получаем результаты асинхронной операции
        double result = await DoWork(progress);
        // отображаем полученное значение
        labelComputed.Text = string.Format("Bar: {0:F2}", result);

        // разрешаем выполнять операцию
        buttonStart.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Преимуществом использования [`Task`-ов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) и `async / await` является простота сочетания асинхронных операций. Много интересных примеров можно прочитать в блоге [Parallel Programming with .NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/).

Comment: А если у меня в методе DoWork выполняется вызов метода, который выполняет вычисления и возвращает string, в цикле, то await не может с ним использоваться. Как тогда быть?

Comment: @AlexeyM: А зачем `ConfigureAwait(false)`? Без него ведь должно работать без проблем?

Comment: @VladD: Небольшая оптимизация: если метод `DoWork()` не относится к UI, то использование `ConfigureAwait(false)` убирает затраты на вызов продолжений метода в контексте синхронизации вызывающего метода (цикл сообщений в WinForms, Dispatcher в WPF, ...).

Comment: @Stepan_Kurennyh: вычисления можно обернуть в

    string result = await Task.Run(() => ComputationWork());

Метод `ComputationWork()` будет вызван в потоке из [пула потоков](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо! этот способ работает и выглядит проще.

Answer (score 2):

Примеров решения конкретно вашей задачи - тьма.

```
void UpdateProgressSafe(int value)
{
     this.progressBar1.Value = value;
}

delegate void UpdateProgressDelegate(int value);

UpdateProgressDelegate UpdateProgress = new UpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateProgressSafe);

progressBar1.Invoke(UpdateProgress, new object[] { 75 });
```

Comment: У WPF-го ProgressBar'a нет метода `Invoke`. В WPF есть `Dispatcher`

Comment: @Donil, да, вы правы, пардоньте :)